# ContentPresenter with ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to use the Single Selection mode for my ItemsControl. So I changed my ItemsControl into a ListBox however I'm getting a exception

> "A style intended for type 'ContentPresenter' cannot be applied to
>   type 'ListBoxItem'."

What's up here? can't i use ContentPresenter for ListBoxes?

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ObservableCollection">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" Background="Beige">
                <clr:Cell Content="{Binding Character}"></clr:Cell>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: If your question has nothing to do with Visual Studio itself then don't use the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style would need to target a ListBoxItem, since that's always what is created.  Some more ListBox template and datatemplate documentation and examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx).

Comment: As far as I can tell the first sentence answers the question while the second line muddies the issue (maybe the example changed?). I would remove the second sentence with an actual example `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">`

Comment: @OmegaMan, the URL points to an example of ListBox with a DataTemplate example.  I do not understand why you think that muddies the issue.

Comment: The user's example has a `DataTemplate` in the `ItemTemplate` which is *also* shown in the link's example.  So it is unclear to me (at least) why the advice of a `DataTemplate` was given to solve the issue which needs a style change.